# duplicate content in phonegap build android app increases size of apk file

Tags: android, ios, cordova

i have a simple php file which get data from server and presents to users. i have checked and its working without any issue. but the size of apk file is 12 Mb. i have checked the phonegap build folder and found that several places complete duplicate folder is there.which is increasing the size of app

can anyone please tell whenther these duplicate contents are required or i can delete so that i can reduce the size of apk file. while making the phonegap apk file i am browsing complete folder of that app for making apK file

here is the structure

C:\Users\jay\fun

fun is the android app name

under fun these files/folders are there

```
.cordova  
hooks
merges
platforms
plugins
www
config.xml
icon.png
```

now under www folder complete phonegap app is there which is able to run android app but under platforms folder

platforms-->android-->assets,bin,cordova,cordovalab,gen,libs,platform_www,res,src folders are there and few files like androidmanifest.xml,build.xml etc are there

i have problem with assets and bin folder

assets folder contains complete www folder and under bin folder again www folder is there and several files and folders which are complete repeat.

while going for making phonegap app i am converting complete fun folder into zip and submitting.please tell if i want to make only android app then is it required to zip fun folder??

if i will zip some specific folder then the size of apk file will be 1/4th of the present size